# Linux keyboard layouts

Tags: java, linux, windows, keyboard-events, keyboard-layout

I am using a java library called JNativehook to receive typing event on Lubuntu and Windows, My problem is when I type a character on Lubuntu with an Arabic keyboard layout I receive the English neighbor of the key, But when I used the library on Windows I was receiving the correct key, Why is this happening ? and how can I fix it ?
Here is my code :

```
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("char: " + e.getKeyChar());
}
```

I download 2.1 from here https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/1stleg/jnativehook/2.1.SNAPSHOT/ , But the problem get even worse, when I type one Arabic character I receive weird characters and a lot of events and this just a small part of the output

```
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (罟)

Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (ý
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (罟)

Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. ()

Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. ()

Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (ý½
Oct 19, 2016 4:43:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: hook_event_proc [314]: Key 0 typed. (罟)
Char:
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how these are translated on Linux, I have changed the backing library which has resoleved the issue in 2.1.

Comment: The version I am using is 2.3

Comment: You are using 2.0.3, 2.1.0 will be the fix version ;)

Comment: But the last binary release is 2.0.3 https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases , Should I compile the source ?

Comment: Yes, there is no official 2.1 build yet.  You will need to compile from src or use the last nightly.  Note that the current master is broken as I try and figure out GlobalScreen refactor. https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/1stleg/jnativehook/2.1.SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Make sure your console supports the wide chars.  It should support wchar_t but that my not be sufficient.  Check java output, not console.

Comment: The problem not just about wired character I received a lot of event for typing one key and sometimes the JVM crash afterword

Comment: Please open a bug on github for the project.  I suspect the width of wchar_t is not sufficient.  Please include the err_###.log that is automatically produced on crash.